# Maximizing a function in Matlab (use of fsolve and derivatives)

Tags: matlab, maximize, derivative, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to find the values for vector `p` (i.e `p(1),p(2),p(3),...`) which maximizes the function `A(p)`.

I am using MATLAB to do that and I found `fsolve` which I thought it could help me. So I made function `A`:

```
function A = myfun(p)

    R  = 0.1; 
    u1 = 500;
    u2 = 400;
    u3 = 300;

    A = ( (p(1)+p(2)+p(3)) * (1/u1+1/u2+1/u3)) * ...
        (1 + R*(p(1)^2+p(2)^2+p(3)^2) * (1/u1+1/u2+1/u3) );
```

And then I need to solve a system of equations which will be:

```
diff(A,p(1))==0

diff(A,p(2))==0

diff(A,p(3))==0
```

where the resulting `p` vector will be the solution to my problem.

How could `fsolve` solve this system of equations (`p0=[1 1 1]`) ?

Comment: where is your symbol?  you need a symbolic variable for diff to work like that.  Either you use numerics, and create a vector domain, and compute finite difference approximation to the derivative, or you create a symbolic variable and perform an analytic derivative.  I'm assuming you chose the fun (symbolic) option.

Comment: I haven't worked with symbolic variables for this and I am not sure how to do that. Maybe I should make a function that calculates diff(A) or if possible to calculate it in function myfun. I am confused on how functions work with their inputs and outputs

Comment: please supply sample inputs, and I will answer and give you code.

Comment: Inputs for which function? p is the vector I want to find so I suppose this is my input no? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it using the symbolic toolbox:

```
%// (there's probably a way to generalize this as well)
dAdp = cellstr(char(...
    [char(diff('C * (p1+p2+p3) * (1 + R*C*(p1^2+p2^2+p3^2))', 'p1')) ';'],...
    [char(diff('C * (p1+p2+p3) * (1 + R*C*(p1^2+p2^2+p3^2))', 'p2')) ';'],...
    [char(diff('C * (p1+p2+p3) * (1 + R*C*(p1^2+p2^2+p3^2))', 'p3')) ';']))

%// convert to proper vector equation
dAdp = regexprep(dAdp, 'p([0-9])', 'p\($1\)');

%// convert to function handle
F = str2func( strcat('@(p) [', dAdp{:}, ']') );
```

but I would not recommend doing it this way (it's completely unreadable and bug-prone).

You could write a proper function and evaluate `dAdp` above using the symbolic toolbox, but I also would not recommend doing it that way (it's just very slow).

I'm a numerical guy, because I trust computers only with what they are built for: *calculations*. Derivations I do on paper, except for the excessively simple, yet long and tedious ones (you could argue that this is such a case, I *still* like doing it on paper, because I also like to exercise my brain :).

I propose you do this, and/or checking yourself continuously using the symbolic toolbox. IMHO, you should use it as an *aid*, not as the main engine.

So, here we go. Here's your function again, this time in a different form, with slightly more brain applied:

```
function A = myfun(p)    
    R = 0.1; 
    u = [500; 400; 300];     
    C = sum(1./u);
    B = C * sum(p) * (1 + R*C*sum(p.^2));
```

So, you want to solve ∇A(**p**) = **0**. Best way is to apply more brain. You may verify that the vectorial derivative is equal to:

```
function F = Aprime(p)
    R = 0.1;
    u = [500; 400; 300];
    C = sum(1./u);
    F = C*( C*R*sum(p.^2) + 2*C*R*p*sum(p) + 1 );
```

which you can either solve with more brain:

> ```
> C·( CR·Σp² + 2CR·p·Σp + 1 ) = 0
>                 Σp² + 2p·Σp = -1/(CR)
> ```
>
> vector == scalar: that means all elements in p are equal.
>   Substituting q = p1 = p2 = p3, then
>
> ```
>  3q² + 2q·3q = -1/(CR)
>          9q² = -1/(CR)
> ```
>
> ⇒             q = ⅓·√(-1/(CR))

(which indicates trouble), or in `fsolve` like so:

```
fsolve(@Aprime, [1 1 1])
```

which will immediately result in

> fsolve completed because the vector of function values at the initial
>   point is near zero as measured by the default value of the function
>   tolerance, and the problem appears regular as measured by the
>   gradient.

which indeed indicates trouble.

Since you have indicated that you're interested in the maximum, and the function does not appear to have stationary points, the only conclusion is that the function has no maximum and no minimum, unless you impose bounds on **p**. Indeed, if you reduce the dimensionality to 2, and make a plot:

```
R = 0.1;
u = [500; 400; 300];
C = sum(1./u);
B = @(p) C * sum(p) .* (1 + R*C*sum(p.^2));

[p1,p2] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10);
surf(p1,p2,reshape(B([p1(:) p2(:)].'), size(p1)), 'edgecolor', 'none')
```

[image]

...there is no extremum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree that it is better to calculate the derivative by hand when possible. But my function A might be different in a way that it will not be easy to calculate its derivative on paper. I would like to make it as automatic as possible. Is there another way to calculate F?

Comment: @user126136: There is the [finite difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) method, which yuo can use to approximate the derivative/gradient. Or, wait for my edit ;)

Comment: @user126136: there you go.

Comment: Thank you so much! You've been more than helpful! You have perfectly solved my initial problem and helped a lot for the whole thing I need to do. Thanks again ;)